# Почему десериализация работает только в одном сеансе программы?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, xml, сериализация

При повторном запуске не десериализует старые файлы.

```
namespace Prog_1
{
public partial class XMLForm : Form
{
    Array Arr = new Array();
    public int[] array1;
    private bool flag;
    Font myFont;

    public XMLForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        LoadFont();
        Font = myFont;
    }

    private void LoadFont()
    {
        PrivateFontCollection private_font = new PrivateFontCollection();
        private_font.AddFontFile("archangelsk_regular.ttf");
        myFont = new Font(private_font.Families[0], 15);
    }

    private void XMLForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        dataGridView1.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.AliceBlue;
        dataGridView1.DefaultCellStyle.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleCenter;
        dataGridView1.ColumnHeadersDefaultCellStyle.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleCenter;
    }

    private void btnClose_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Close();
    }

    private void btnGen_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        btnSaveF1.Enabled = true;
        btnSaveF2.Enabled = true;
        dataGridView1.Rows.Clear();
        textBox1.Text = "";
        Arr.N = (int)nudN.Value;
        Arr.A = (int)nudA.Value;
        Arr.B = (int)nudB.Value;
        Arr.RandomArray(out array1, out flag);
        if (flag)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < (int)nudN.Value; i++)
            {
                try
                {
                    textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text + array1[i].ToString();
                    textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text + " ";
                    dataGridView1.Rows.Add();
                    dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value = i;
                    dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value = array1[i];
                }
                catch (Exception e1)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(e1.Message);
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            nudA.Value = 0;
            nudB.Value = 0;
        }
    }
    private void dataGridView1_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void btnSaveF1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Arr.mass = array1;
        Arr.Serialization(Arr);
    }

    private void btnReadF1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Arr.Deserialization(Arr);
        textBox1.Text = "";
        dataGridView1.Rows.Clear();
        nudN.Value = Arr.N;
        nudA.Value = Arr.A;
        nudB.Value = Arr.B;
        for (int i = 0; i < Arr.mass.Length; i++)
        {
            try
            {
                textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text + Arr.mass[i].ToString();
                textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text + " ";
                dataGridView1.Rows.Add();
                dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value = i;
                dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value = Arr.mass[i];
            }
            catch (Exception e1)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(e1.Message);
            }
        }
    }

    private void btnSaveF2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void btnReadF2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
}


namespace Prog_1
{
[Serializable]
public class Array
{
    public int N { get; set; }
    public int A { get; set; }
    public int B { get; set; }
    public int[] mass {get;set;}

    public Array()
    {
        N = 0;
        A = 0;
        B = 0;
    }

    // public bool Flag { get; set; }
    public void RandomArray(out int[] array,out bool Flag)
    {
        array = new int[N];
        Flag = true;
        Random rand = new Random();
        if (A <= B)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
                array[i] = rand.Next(A, B + 1);
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Неправильный диапазон, введите заново");
            Flag = false;
        }
    }

    public void Serialization(object E)
    {
        try
        {
            SaveFileDialog saveFileDialog1 = new SaveFileDialog();
            saveFileDialog1.Filter = "XML|*.xml";
            if (saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                // передаем в конструктор тип класса
                XmlSerializer formatter = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Array));
                // получаем поток, куда будем записывать сериализованный объект
                using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(saveFileDialog1.FileName, FileMode.Create))
                {
                    //Array t = new Array(); 
                    formatter.Serialize(fs, E);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }

    public void Deserialization(object E)
    {
        try
        {
            OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog();
            ofd.Filter = "XML|*.xml";
            if (ofd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                XmlSerializer formatter = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Array));
                // десериализация
                using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(ofd.FileName, FileMode.Open))
                {
                    E = (Array)formatter.Deserialize(fs);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: а где тут, простите, у вас десериализация?

Comment: Постарайтесь уменьшить код до минимального, который воспроизводит проблему. Например, вряд ли процедура `LoadFont()` имеет отношение к десериализации. А также поле `dataGridView1`.